# Retrieving Sandbox entitlements from an XPC bundle

Tags: macos, security, sandbox, osx-mavericks, xpc

It's usually possible to see if sandbox entitlements exist for an application with the *codesign* command line call. For example, calling this

```
codesign --display --entitlements :- /Applications/Notes.app/ | grep sandbox
```

Will result in this output

```
Executable=/Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/Notes
<key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
```

Where the key com.apple.security.app-sandbox denotes that the app runs in a sandbox.

On Mavericks, some XPC helper apps show in Activity Monitor to be running in a sandbox, but calling codesign on them doesn't reveal anything. An example for one of Safari's XPC helper applications: -

```
codesign -display --entitlements :- /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent | grep sandbox
```

Just returns this: -

```
Executable=/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
```

I've also tried checking programatically if the bundle is sandboxed, with the code described in [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/checking-code-signing-and-sandboxing-status-in-code/), but again, returns as not sandboxed, even though Activity Monitor clearly states that it is.

Is it possible to check such an xpc bundle, to see if will be executed in a sandbox and uses sandbox entitlements?

Answer (score 2):

Looking for the com.apple.security.app-sandbox entitlement as you're doing is the way to check if an XPC service uses App Sandbox. The reason that the Safari Web Content process shows up as sandboxed despite not having this entitlement is that it does not use App Sandbox, but rather lower level interfaces to the underlying [sandbox facility](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/sandbox.7.html) in OS X. Early on the web content process calls WebKit's [initializeSandbox()](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit2/Shared/mac/ChildProcessMac.mm?rev=157137#L160) method, which uses a system private interface to apply a [sandbox policy](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit2/WebProcess/com.apple.WebProcess.sb.in?rev=157137) at runtime. So finding out whether a given XPC service will create a sandboxed process is as difficult as finding out whether that service will call a function. However, if you're curious about the restrictions placed on such processes the sandbox policy is usually stored in a `.sb` file somewhere on the system. In this case it's at `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit2.framework/Versions/A/Resources/com.apple.WebProcess.sb`.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful. Is there any way to match a binary to the .sb that it will use?

Comment: No, as the file can have any name. For research purposes it's often related to the process name though. For example, the .sb for the storeagent process is /System/Library/Sandbox/Profiles/com.apple.storeagent.sb.